# song.currentTime returning undefined

Tags: javascript

Before I ask my question I just wanted to say that I'm a noob to Javascript and to StackOverflow in general so I wanted to apologize in advance if this question is too dumb.

Anyways, I'm learning Javascript and right now I'm experimenting with currentTime, but for some reason song.currentTime is returning undefined, and I also can't set the currentTime. Here is my code:

```
<audio autoplay>
<source src="A.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="awesomeness">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    console.log("letting everything preload by waiting 2 seconds");
     var song= document.getElementById("awesomeness");
     console.log(song.currentTime);
     song.currentTime=30;
}
</script>
```

Here it is in action (look at the console output): http://dancingcats.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: which browser and browser version you are using ?

Comment: @JayantiLal Chrome, but someone already solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) property belongs to the [audio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)([Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement))

You need is to set it to the audio element not to the source element

```
<audio autoplay id="awesomeness">
<source src="A.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thanks.